# C linking stage generates no warning

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

I have the following files:

main.c :

```
int f(void);  
int main(void)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

f.c:

```
char *f = "linker";
```

GNUMakefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all: main

main: main.o f.o

main.o: main.c
f.o: f.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

When running the makefile I get no compilation warnings/errors. Why?

Comment: for extra fun, change that to `char *f="\xeb\x1f\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x8d\x4e\x08\x89\x46"
"\x0c\x8d\x56\x0c\x89\xf3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x40\xcd"
"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you lied to the compiler ... and it trusts you.

In main.c you told the compiler `f` is a function (**declaration / prototype**), but `f` is, in fact, a pointer to a (unmodifiable) character array of length 7 defined in f.c (**definition**).

**Don't lie to the compiler.**

Comment: So the compiler just checks if the symbol is defined at linking stage, nothing more ?

Comment: Basically yes. If you compile the two files at the same time (`gcc f.c main.c`) it may be able to do a more thorough analysis.

Comment: you should distinguish between "declaration" and "definition". in "declaration" you say: THIS IS IT, trust me, i tell you so. In "definition" you actually provide the implementation/the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You've told the compiler f is a function. It isn't but there's no obligation on implementations to record the type which would be needed to warn here. Gcc doesn't, some other implementations might.

The workaround is to put the declaration of f into a header and include that in each translation unit which will make the error obvious.

Answer (score 0):

if you put the declaration int f(void); into a header-file which you include from both files, you will get the exprected compiler-error. In your present case, compile-wise all is fine.

in the makefile i miss the gcc main.c part and the ln part